# Testing Spring Environment Profiles with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

The latest version of Spring Framework has deprecated 
[Environment.acceptsProfiles(String ...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#acceptsProfiles-java.lang.String...-) in favour of [Environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles ...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#acceptsProfiles-org.springframework.core.env.Profiles-)

Updating this in one of my applications has made testing more difficult, here is some test code to demonstrate the issue:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Profiles;
import org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment;

public class EnvironmentProfilesTest {

    @Test
    public void testItWithRealEnvironment() {
        System.setProperty(StandardEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "adrian");
        Environment environment = new org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment();

        ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested(environment);
        assertTrue(toBeTested.hello("adrian"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testItWithMocklEnvironment() {
        Environment environment = mock(Environment.class);
when(environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("adrian"))).thenReturn(true);

        ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested(environment);
        assertTrue(toBeTested.hello("adrian"));
    }

    private static class ToBeTested {
        private Environment env;
        public ToBeTested(Environment env) {
            this.env = env;
        }

        public boolean hello(String s) {
            return env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of(s));
        }
    }
}
```

The old version using a String argument to acceptsProfiles was easy to mock. What am I doing wrong? It feels like the Profiles class might benefit an equals() method?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't Spring, it's just incorrect approach. As I can see the problem is in this part of code:
`when(environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("adrian"))).thenReturn(true);`

You use mock for `Environment` and try to catch instance of `Profiles` class, something like:
`.acceptsProfiles(eq(Profiles.of("adrian")))`. You can't catch it because you create another instance in the method `boolean hello(String s)` and `Environment` never returns true.

You just described incorrect behavior for the mock `Environment` and you can fix it:

**put `any`**

```
@Test
    public void testItWithMocklEnvironment() {
        Environment environment = mock(Environment.class);
        when(environment.acceptsProfiles(any(Profiles.class))).thenReturn(true);

        ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested(environment);
        assertTrue(toBeTested.hello("adrian"));
    }
```

or  **don't use mock** (I think this is what you're looking for):

```
@Test
    public void testItWithMocklEnvironment() {
        Environment environment = new org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment();
        ((StandardEnvironment) environment).setActiveProfiles("adrian");

        ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested(environment);
        assertTrue(toBeTested.hello("adrian"));
    }
```

Comment: As of 5.2.8, `when(environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("adrian")))` should now work.  It seems it's been fixed in 2020 by [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/14d539017cffbf534794dc9fbb8a9bc9b21ea07b) following this [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25340).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a simple matcher based on the **toString**.

```
public static Profiles profiles(String... profiles) {
    return argThat(argument -> {
        String expected = Objects.toString(Profiles.of(profiles));
        String actual = Objects.toString(argument);
        return expected.equals(actual);
    });
}
```

Then you use the matcher as follows:

```
when(environment.acceptsProfiles(profiles("myProfile"))).thenReturn(true);
```